# How do you deploy Craft 3 on Heroku with Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm relatively new to Craft 3, and am able to run Craft locally with a Postgres db and Valet as my server. When I try to deploy to Heroku, I run into issues with (I think) Postgres.

**Background**

I tried setting up Craft to work with Heroku by following [this guide](https://torbensko.com/posts/2019/creating-a-site-using-craftcms-heroku-and-cloudcannon/) (see the "Publishing" section near the bottom of the guide). I found that if I just run a `heroku create` and then push my local branch to the remote server, I get an "Internal Server Error" when loading the remote site on Heroku.

Instead, I created an `app.json` file as per [this guide](https://github.com/edenspiekermann/craft3-heroku-starterkit) by @edenspiekermann. Then I run `https://heroku.com/deploy` with arguments to create the Heroku app, and this allows me to access the Craft admin page at /admin/install on the remote server.

Following the [first guide](https://torbensko.com/posts/2019/creating-a-site-using-craftcms-heroku-and-cloudcannon/), I also push my local Postgres database to Heroku with `heroku pg:push DB_NAME DATABASE_URL --app HEROKU_APP_NAME`.

**Questions**

-How does Heroku know the right `DATABASE_URL` to use in `/config/db.php`? Locally, that variables comes from `.env` which is not pushed to my repo or Heroku.

-Why does Heroku show an internal server error if I just push my local branch to the remote server (whereas creating a Heroku app with https://heroku.com/deploy works)?

My `db.php` file:

```
preg_match('|postgres://([a-z0-9]*):([a-z0-9]*)@([^:]*):([0-9]*)/(.*)|i', getenv('DATABASE_URL'), $matches);

$user = $matches[1];
$password = $matches[2];
$server = $matches[3];
$port = $matches[4];
$database = $matches[5];

return [
  'driver' => "pgsql",
  'server' => $server,
  'user' => $user,
  'password' => $password,
  'database' => $database,
  'schema' => getenv('DB_SCHEMA'),
  'tablePrefix' => getenv('DB_TABLE_PREFIX'),
  'port' => $port
];
```

My `Procfile` for Heroku:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 web/
```

My `.env` file:

```
# The environment Craft is currently running in ('dev', 'staging', 'production', etc.)
ENVIRONMENT="dev"

# The secure key Craft will use for hashing and encrypting data
SECURITY_KEY=""

# The database driver that will be used ('mysql' or 'pgsql')
DB_DRIVER="pgsql"

# The database server name or IP address (usually this is 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1')
DB_SERVER="localhost"

# The database username to connect with
DB_USER="atc"

# The database password to connect with
DB_PASSWORD=""

# The name of the database to select
DB_DATABASE="blogdb"

# The database schema that will be used (PostgreSQL only)
DB_SCHEMA="public"

# The prefix that should be added to generated table names (only necessary if multiple things are sharing the same database)
DB_TABLE_PREFIX=""

# The port to connect to the database with. Will default to 5432 for PostgreSQL and 3306 for MySQL.
DB_PORT="5432"

DATABASE_URL="postgres://atc:@localhost:5432/blogdb"

DEFAULT_SITE_URL="https://landing-page.dev"
```

Error I receive when navigating to homepage on Heroku after I've pushed my local Postgres db to Heroku remote:

```
HTTP 503 – Service Unavailable – craft\web\ServiceUnavailableHttpException
```

Comment: Was able to figure out the answer to my two questions (by setting the `ENVIRONMENT` and `SECURITY_KEY` in Config Vars of the Settings dashboard in Heroku). How getting a HTTP 503 "Service Unavailable" error when navigating to the remote server :(

Answer (score 1):

Found out that there are a variety of Config vars in Heroku you need to set that match your local .env file. In particular:

- ENVIRONMENT
- SECURITY_KEY
- DB_SCHEMA

**Edit 10.1.19** Wrote [this tutorial](https://dev.to/coda/how-to-deploy-craft-cms-with-postgres-on-heroku-1c2h) on how to get Craft 3 up and running on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Craft/Yii on Heroku has been made much simpler with the addition of the `url` config option:

```php
<?php return [
    // ...
    'production' => [
        'url' => getenv('DATABASE_URL')
    ]
    // ...
];
```

I think there are too many factors for us to say why the one-click deploy works, but pushing an existing application doesn't—it could be that one of the custom environment variables isn't populated (as it would be with Heroku's deploy/app wizard).